# VSTS Build is creating an archive with a subfolder. How to avoid this?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS online and created a build (for ASP.NET Core). The build and release are working fine.

However, I find that the deployment happens inside a folder a on the target site (Azure Web site service).

When I saw the log for the step "archive files", in the build, I see it is using 7zip and here is the command that it ran -

```
7z.exe a -tzip D:\a\1\a\14.zip a
```

And the zip file thus have a sub-folder 'a' and the deployment just deployed the folder a and its content to the wwwroot.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unchecking "Prefix root folder name to archive paths" option in "Archive files" task.